# Soma de números da direita para a esquerda

Tags: c, visualg

Preciso fazer a soma dos dígitos de um número digitado pelo usuário.

**Por exemplo:**

- Se a entrada igual a 20, fazer 2 + 0 = 2
- Se a entrada igual a 45, fazer 4 + 5 = 9

Podem ser usados VisualG e C.

Comment: Você fez alguma coisa até agora? Precisamos avaliar seu código para poder ajudar!

Comment: Tentei usar o enquanto. Em VisualG, mas não dá certo. do tipo. Enquanto num%10. Escreva(num), mas esta a dar erro

Comment: Edite a pergunta ([clicando aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/316581/edit) se não souber como) e adicione o código que já fez e até onde tentou

Comment: Só pode ser digitado dois números ou não tem limite?

Comment: Edita sua pergunta ai em cima no botão editar e posta o código... Vou tentar olhar aqui seu código.

Comment: Tu pode manter o input como string e iterar por cada caractere... vai facilitar bastante.

Comment: @MartinDala coloquei a solução, testei ta ok!

Answer (score 0):

Usa o resto da divisão por 10:

```
int resto= 20 % 10; //obtem o resto da divisão por 10
int valorSemDireita= 20 / 10; //Como é um inteiro vai retirar o nº da direita
resultado= resto + valorSemDireita;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pressupondo que esse número de entrada possa ser de 0 a várias casas decimais.

A lógica para resolver o problema  seria de individualmente dividir o número por 10 até chegar a 0;

***Então o código pode ficar assim:***

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,soma=0,aux;
    printf("Digite um numero:");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    while(a!=0)
    {
        aux=a%10;
        a=a/10;
     soma+=aux;
    }
    printf("\nA soma dos digitos eh:%d",soma);
}
```